# Spoofing URLs with file_get_contents() in PHP

Tags: php, file-get-contents, spoofing, websecurity

In PHP, I sometimes use `file_get_contents()` to call a remote URL for advertising partner callbacks. I'll take an incoming traffic identifier (tid) in the URL, and then URL decode that `$_GET` call, and then URL encode before sending via `file_get_contents()`.

Is there a potential security risk where the URL that I compose in `file_get_contents()` could be ignored and a second URL (such as local file access) be utilized, simply by spoofing one of the TIDs that I read such as what comes in via `$_GET['tid1']` ?

Comment: Did you apply proper URL encoding to the parameter?

Comment: I used the standard `urldecode()` when pulled off the `$_GET`, and then `urlencode() `when passing to `file_get_contents()`..

Comment: You don’t need `urldecode` for `$_GET`, PHP has already applied it.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks on that. Learned something new. Proof is in the warning on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php